# Connect two microdata items that are not in the same scope

Tags: html, seo, microdata, rich-snippets

Lets assume my html page looks like this:

`<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/videoObject">`

`<span itemprop="name">My Video Name</span>`

`</div>`

...rest of the page...

`<textarea rows="7" cols="54" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $embedUrl?></textarea>`

I want to add an itemprop="embedUrl" for the textarea as it contains the embeded code for my videoobject, but since it's not in my div, as this is the way the page is designed, I have to create a new videoobject in order to specify that. How can I extend the scope of my original videoobject to contain the textarea, even-though it's not in the original div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is what the `itemref` attribute is for.

You use it like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/videoObject" itemref="mytextarea">
    <span itemprop="name">My Video Name</span>
</div>
```

...rest of the page...

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="54" readonly="readonly" 
    id="mytextarea" itemprop="embedUrl"><?php echo $embedUrl?></textarea>
```

The `itemref` attribute must be on the same element as the `itemscope` attribute and takes a space separated list of ids of elements with itemprop attributes.

For more information, check out this [HTML5 Doctor article on microdata](http://html5doctor.com/microdata/)

Comment: Great article, explains much better than schema.org or Google's page...Thanks.